# Stopping coroutine or changing while loop condition freezes game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, while-loop

Just as the name implies, I have a coroutine for spawning enemies in my unity game. If I stop the coroutine for spawning or if change the while loop condition from false to true, the entire game freezes except my weapon that follows mouse position. Bullets no longer move and enemies no longer move even though their movement is defined outside of the coroutine. Any help would be appreciated. In this version of my code. I have an if statement that stops the coroutine.

```
public class Spawn_Manager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject _monsterPrefab;
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject _enemyContainer;

    private bool _stopSpawn = false;

    public GameObject[] SpawnPoints;
    public GameObject randomPoint;
    public GameObject WaveSpawn;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        SpawnPoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Spawns");
        StartCoroutine(SpawnRoutine());

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Timer.timeLeft <= 0)
        {
            _stopSpawn = true;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator SpawnRoutine()
    {
        while (_stopSpawn == false)
        {
            
            for (int i = 0; i < StageMode.NumberToSpawn; i++)
            {
                randomPoint = SpawnPoints[Random.Range(0, SpawnPoints.Count())];
                GameObject newMonster = Instantiate(_monsterPrefab, randomPoint.transform.position, randomPoint.transform.rotation);
                newMonster.transform.parent = _enemyContainer.transform.parent;
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(StageMode.SpawnDelay);

                if (i == StageMode.SpawnCounter)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < StageMode.WavesToSpawn; j++)
                    {
                        for (int k = 0; k < SpawnPoints.Length; k++)
                        {
                            Instantiate(_monsterPrefab, SpawnPoints[k].transform.position, SpawnPoints[k].transform.rotation);
                        }
                    }
                    i = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**
I was able to fix the problem. My coroutine wasn't freezing the game, time was stopping which ceased all movement in my GameObjects. When I fixed that, my coroutine wasn't stopping which I also fixed.

In my timer code I used this and removed Time.timeScale which I used without fully understanding it.

```
    {
        if (timeLeft > 0)
        {
            timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
            FillTimer.fillAmount = timeLeft / maxTime;
        }
        else if (timeLeft <= 0)
        {
            Spawn_Manager.stopSpawn = true;

        }
    }
```

And in my spawn manager I made some changes to how the coroutine runs

```
private IEnumerator Enemies;

void Start() 
{
        SpawnPoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Spawns");
        Enemies = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy");
        coroutine = SpawnRoutine();
        StartCoroutine(coroutine);
}
void Update()
{
    if (stopSpawn == true)
    {
        StopCoroutine(coroutine);
    }
```

This fixed all my problems. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is very simple, your while loop is always running because your are not setting `_stopSpawn = true` .

And one suggestion, `static` are not threadsafe are so be careful.

Comment: Even when I have the if statement change the condition of _stopSpawn = true, it still does the same thing.

Comment: Which if condition? So can you put a breakpoint and see whether is it hitting that line.

Comment: Yeah, its not hitting that if statement in my update function.